# QWebEngineView - Allow local Store in the Browser

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm trying to implement a web browser to see the web page ['https://earth.google.com/web'](https://earth.google.com/web).
The browser works fine.
The browser save my google user, so when I start a new sesion, I don't have to put my google user, for using my settings.
My problem occurs when I upload a KML track, the program says 'To save this file, enable local store in the browser.

[image]

In Python console I saw this message:

```
js: 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
```

If the track is not saved, when I start a new sesion, the KML is not there.

I try this this:

```
# Creation of Widget
self.web_view = QWebEngineView() 

# Setting the Browser
settings = QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()

# Setting Local Storage
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)

# Other settings I tried:
    

settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.ScreenCaptureEnabled, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins, True)
settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptCanPaste, True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to enable attributes such as [`QWebEngineSettings::LocalStorageEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum) since they are enabled by default but you have to accept the [`QWebEngineQuotaRequest`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginequotarequest.html) associated with the [`quotaRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#quotaRequested) signal:

```
self.web_view.page().quotaRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
```

Comment: In Pyqt6 it doesn't works (don't save data). Any idea why?